Precision of estimates of lower bit error probabilities at higher SNR
For my university lab in wireless communications, I simulated a simple uncoded BPSK (binary phase shift keying) channel with AWGN (additive white gaussian noise) to estimate the BER (bit error rate) using MLE (maximum likelihood estimation), as a sort of introductory task. The number of monte carlo runs $N_{\mathrm{MC}}$ for each SNR (signal-to-noise ratio) from -20dB to +10dB was indirectly set via a target error count $N_{\mathrm{err}}$. Looking at the resulting plots with a log scaled y axis, the size of the Wilson score confidence intervals appears to only be affected by $N_{\mathrm{err}}$.

Intuitively, this makes sense as the width scales with $\frac{1}{\sqrt{N_{\mathrm{MC}}}}$. Given that this is such a simple channel model, we also know that the true BER is $Q(\sqrt{2 \mathrm{SNR}})$ and the MLE just converges to it for a large enough sample size. So far so good, but I also noticed when looking at the resulting monte carlo runs versus the SNR, that the lower BER at a higher SNR for a fixed $N_{\mathrm{err}}$ required a larger sample size for enough error events to occur. 
Given that the purpose of this task is probably to teach us about the trade off between precision of estimates and computational load, I am now confused whether the larger sample size at higher SNRs actually implies a higher confidence for those low BER estimates. On the other hand, it also feels counterintuitive insofar as a lower probability obviously requires a larger sample size to be estimated. If the low BER/high SNR estimates are indeed more precise, do the symmetric relative error bars on the log plot even make sense? I would assume in that case that absolute error bars would be less visually misleading.
Edit: explained acronyms as per request
